# SQL error (too few parameters)

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select productline, P.productcode, productname, (OD.priceeach - P.buyprice) as ProfitMargin
from Products P, OrderDetails OD
where P.productcode = OD.productcode and productline like '%Cars%'
order by ProfitMargin desc
```

when i run it, there's an error. It says "**too few parameters. Expected 1.**"
Is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

When you construct a query in Microsoft Access, you can use "parameters" by inserting the parameter name, surrounded by square brackets, in your SQL statement. Of course, you can also put square brackets around the name of a field (or a table); the interpretation of the square brackets is somewhat ambiguous.

Access will search for the name inside the square brackets first in the field names, then in the table names, and only if it does not find the name in one of these lists will it treat the name as a parameter name.